# DatabaseReference import working but FirebaseBase not able to import

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on android with firebase database.... using firebase tool i connected to firebase and added the firebase database using the statement

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

I am able to import Database Reference but not FirebaseDatabase

my gradle(app) file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yadav.yadavapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My mainactivity file

```
package com.example.yadav.yadavapp;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference; ///working
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase; //cannot import

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error?

Answer (score 0):

this is not logical, because it's one and the same package.

Android Studio would simply remove all unused imports

... *unless* you use them within your `MainActivity`.

for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   /* when declaring these, it should import both of them */
   protected FirebaseDatabase fb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   protected DatabaseReference defaultRef = null;

   public MainActivity() {}

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```

Comment: It is illogicial but what i am saying i am able to import DatabaseeReference but not FirebaseDatabase though they belong to same package

Comment: @YadavShri have you tried to use them, as shown above? if not doing so, the `import` statement would just disappear. this can be useful to keep the imports clean, but it also can be bothersome, when trying to find classes in packages. there might even be an option to disable that IDE behavior, because it not always was alike that. meanwhile, one barely has to import anything manually anymore; and in case of, it's `<Alt> + <Enter>`.